# Problem about concavity and definition of points

Tags: calculus

> Given the graph of $f(x)$ below, which is defined on the interval $I=[A,B]$

[image]
>

> then the function $f(x)$ is **concave down** in the interval
>
> 1. $[A,B]$
> 2. $[A,B)$
> 3. $(A,B]$
> 4. $(A,B)$

I need to understand the concept and idea about this question, what is the effect of not being defined at the terminal point of an interval.

Please make some explanation in details so that I can understand the idea.

Comment: Logically, any choice being true implies that 4) is true.

Comment: Can you write down the definition of "concave down" you've been given ? Then check how it applies to points $A$ and $C$ or $C$ and $B$, where $A<C<B$... Otherwise, is it on purpose that the axis 'x' and 'y' are interchanged compared to the usual representation ? (once that is corrected, you should conclude that 1 and 2 are wrong, 3 and 4 are right).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English terms, a function is **concave down** on an interval if it sits *above* any segment joining two points of its graph. This is true on $(A,B]$, so the answer is $(3)$.

You can see that if you join $(A, f(A))$ with a point halfway between $A$ and $B$, like $\left(\frac{A+B}{2},f\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)\right)$, the function sits *below* this line.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is 3 - $(A,B]$. Conceptually, the function is concave there, since if we connect any two points along $f$ within $(A,B]$, the line passes "not above" (beneath or touching) the function between the two intersection points. $A$ is excluded since obviously the line connecting $(A, f(A))$ to any other point on $f$ results in a line that is always above the function, for some point $A + \epsilon$ for sufficiently small $\epsilon$.